# read a file(.txt,.csv..xls) and assign them to respective variable in python script

Tags: python, file, file-io

i have a file(mail.txt) and that have content like

```
 emailfrom = 'satya@gmail.com'
 emailto = 'abc@hcl.com','xyz@hcl.com','accc@infy.com'
 filepath = 'D:\A_2.csv'
 subject = 'sells report for xyz'
 body = 'hi axx,find the attached file of sells.'
```

And i am running a script to send mail and in my script my msg variables 
  emailfrom,emailto,filepath,subject,body are present.

So how can i read that text file and read values from there and assign variables to my script variables.

please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to hold the information, with `ast.literal_eval()` to properly evaluate your strings and `tuple`s (or else you would end up with extra `'` everywhere):

```
import ast
with open('mail.txt') as f:
    d = {k:ast.literal_eval(v) for k,v in (line.strip().split(' = ') for line in f)}
```

You will then have a dictionary holding each value:

```
>>> print(*d.items(), sep='\n')
('emailfrom', 'satya@gmail.com')
('emailto', ('abc@hcl.com', 'xyz@hcl.com', 'accc@infy.com'))
('filepath', 'D:\\A_2.csv')
('body', 'hi axx,find the attached file of sells.')
('subject', 'sells report for xyz')
```

Access the values as you would expect:

```
>>> d['subject']
'sells report for xyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   objFile = open("youfile.txt", "r")


   lsFileContents = objFile.readlines()
   strEmailFrom = lsFileContents[0].strip().split("=")[1].strip()
   strEmailTo = lsFileContents[1].strip().split("=")[1].strip()  
   strFilePath = lsFileContents[2].strip().split("=")[1].strip()
   strBody = lsFileContents[4].strip().split("=")[1].strip()
   strSubject = lsFileContents[3].strip().split("=")[1].strip()

   objFile.close()
```

Comment: This would end up saving the whole line to each variable, e.g. `strEmailFrom` would be `"emailfrom = 'satya@gmail.com'"`.

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal is what i am getting.

Comment: can i give whole path of file inside open()?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, code is working fine at my side. It may be some other error at your side.

Comment: "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'readLines'"    if i need to import any module for that

Comment: instead of with open("youfile.txt", "r") as objFile: try objFile = open("youfile.txt", "r")

Comment: I have modified code. Try that out.